# how to extract href from <a> element using lxml cssselctor?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml, lxml.html

```
def extract_page_data(html):
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
item_sel = CSSSelector('.my-item')
text_sel = CSSSelector('.my-text-content')
time_sel = CSSSelector('.time')
author_sel = CSSSelector('.author-text')
a_tag = CSSSelector('.a')

    for item in item_sel(tree):
    yield {'href': a_tag(item)[0].text_content(),
           'my pagetext': text_sel(item)[0].text_content(),
           'time': time_sel(item)[0].text_content().strip(),
           'author': author_sel(item)[0].text_content()}
```

I want to extract `href` but I am not able to extract it using this code

Comment: Along with the solution that sir Andersson has already provided, you need to modify your selector call like `.cssselect()` not `.CSSSelector()`.

Comment: like this sir ? a_tag = cssselect('.a') and thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. It seems you did things differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to extract `@href` as

```
'href': a_tag(item)[0].attrib['href']
```

or

```
'href': a_tag(item)[0].get('href')
```

As an option you can also use XPath

```
tree.xpath(".//a/@href")
```

Comment: (item).xpath(".//a/@href")[0].strip() this worked
Thank you sir :)